# Duvida de arquitetura de sistemas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Boa tarde, tenho que alterar o sistema aqui da empresa, e vai ficar mais complexo. Somos uma construtora cada obra que trabalhamos é orçado previamente, quando o comprador vai adicionar um pedido, o sistema tem que verificar se existe uma requisição de compra feita pelo pessoal da obra com esse material, depois o sistema tem que verificar se o material está no orçamento, e depois verificar se os valores unitários não são maiores no pedido do que no orçamento, depois verificar a mesma coisa para o valor total... cada material que o comprador adiciona umd acesso no banco de dados, carregando uma lista de orçamento e fazendo as validações, teria que ser assim mesmo? Que estratégia vocês utilizariam para resolver isso?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta e o que você deseja, você poderia editar ela e esclarecer mais um pouco?

Answer (score 1):

Se você não deseja fazer várias requisições ao banco de dados, o que sinceramente não acho que seja um problema quando os métodos são bem implementados, e o retorno das consultas não tem grande quantidade de dados, então você poderá fazer outra abordagem. Sendo implementar uma procedure no banco de dados, onde você implementar todas as suas regras de negócio que você citou acima.

Entretanto, essa não é uma prática de colocar regras de negócio dentro do banco de dados não é muito bem aceita diante da maioria dos patterns de desenvolvido aplicados no mercado, contudo algumas raras vezes é a unica solução.

Agora se você não quiser deixar dentro do banco de dados, e nem fazer muitos acessos ao banco de dados na sua camada de aplicação, então você poderia considerar implementar algum tipo de serviço assíncrono, podendo usar um webservice para isso. Mas você terá que avaliar muito bem o impacto pois poderá impactar na usabilidade do software.

Espero ter ajudado.